# Is it possible to use multiple String.Split Intersection as a string which could be run and stored to a list

Tags: vb.net

I have checkbox selections in my VB form using which I want to decide if I want to run a String Split function. I have six string fields which contain comma separated values which I want to compare and find if there are values common to all the strings.

My current option is do If Else for each possible condition but since I have 6 fields, I need to have 2 ^ 6 results in my code which is lengthy. I am providing a snippet for two fields to give an idea of my current approach.

```
    Dim masterFormList = "AAA,BBB,CCC,FFF,GGG,HHH"
    Dim otherList = "XXX,BBB,YYY,AAA"

    Dim r = 0 'will replace these using checkboxes
    Dim k = 1 'will replace these using checkboxes
    Dim c As Char() = New Char() {","c}

    Dim matches =
    If(r = 1,
       (If(k = 1,
    otherList.Split(c).Intersect(masterFormList.Split(c)).ToList(),
    otherList.Split(c))),
    (If(k = 1,
        masterFormList.Split(c).ToList(),
    Nothing)))
```

I want to know if there is a simpler way of doing this.

Comment: omg, that if statement...

Comment: lol. I was thinking how will I do 64 cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand what you want to do. You would put your list inside an other list.

```
    Dim combinedList As New List(Of String)
    combinedList.Add(masterFormList)
    combinedList.Add(otherList)
```

If I understand, r and k represent the index of the list you want to compare.

```
    Dim matches = combinedList(r).Split(c).Intersect(combinedList(k).Split(c)).ToList()
```

If you need to intersect more than 2 list you just need to do them one after the other.

```
    Dim matches = combinedList(r).Split(c)
    matches = matches.Intersect(combinedList(k).Split(c)).ToList()
    matches = matches.Intersect(combinedList(z).Split(c)).ToList()
    ...
```

Comment: Those would be checkbox selections. If checkbox selection is true. Want an intersection of only those lists which which have been checked in the form.

Comment: But your logic would make things better. In the given example only two conditions would do the job.

Comment: @MeraNaamParker if you want to intersect more list together, just do them one after the other (this could be done in a loop if r,k,... are in a list)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer Lotus and apologies for the late reply. I was travelling over the last couple of days. But your suggestion worked perfectly fine and ended up a lot simpler than what I thought. I am still a noob at  programming. but getting a hang of things pretty quick. Posting the code which I finally ended up using.

```
    For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            If box1.checked Then
                            If IsDBNull(row.Item("Column1")) = False Then
                            CombinedList.Add(row.Item("Column1"))
                            End If
                    End If
            If box2.Checked Then
                             If IsDBNull(row.Item("Column2")) = False Then
                            CombinedList.Add(row.Item("Column2"))
                             End If
            End If
                    If box3.checked Then
                     If IsDBNull(row.Item("Column3")) = False Then
                                    CombinedList.Add(row.Item("Column3"))
                             End If
            End If
                    If box4.checked Then
                            If IsDBNull(row.Item("Column4")) = False Then
                                    CombinedList.Add(row.Item("Column4"))
                            End If
            End If
                    If box5.checked Then
                    If IsDBNull(row.Item("Column5")) = False Then
                                    CombinedList.Add(row.Item("Column5"))
                            End If
            End If
                    If CombinedList.Count > 0 Then
               Dim ConsolidatedListArr = CombinedList(0).Split(c)
                       Dim CommonListArr = CombinedList(0).Split(c)
                   For Each item In CombinedList
                               ConsolidatedClientsArr = ConsolidatedClientsArr.Union(item.Split(c)).ToArray()
                               CommonClientsArr = CommonClientsArr.Intersect(item.Split(c)).ToArray()
                   Next
                       Consolidatedstring = String.Join(",", ConsolidatedClientsArr.ToArray())
               CommonString = String.Join(",", CommonClientsArr.ToArray())
                    End If
    Next
```